# how to golang Unmarshal a xml message into a struct

Tags: xml, go

how to decode this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LocationConstraint>oss-cn-hangzhou</LocationConstraint>
```

my code is like this:

```
type BucketLocation struct {
    LocationConstraint string `xml:"LocationConstraint"`
}
v := &BucketLocation{}
xml.Unmarshal(xml_content, v)
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of your struct implies the following XML format which doesn't match what you're providing:

```
<BucketLocation>
    <LocationConstraint>oss-cn-hangzhou</LocationConstraint>
</BucketLocation>
```

To read the example XML that you've given you would do something this:

```
var v string
xml.Unmarshal(xml_content, &v)
```